# cannot import name ContextualZipFile when installing Cython

Tags: python, cython

I downloaded Cython and run:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

and I get the following error:

```
Unable to find pgen, not compiling formal grammar.
running install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 357, in <module>
    **setup_args
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 67, in run
    self.do_egg_install()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 98, in do_egg_install
    easy_install = self.distribution.get_command_class('easy_install')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 388, in get_command_class
    self.cmdclass[command] = cmdclass = ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2088, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 42, in <module>
    from setuptools.archive_util import unpack_archive
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/archive_util.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import ensure_directory, ContextualZipFile
ImportError: cannot import name ContextualZipFile
```

I also get the same error when I install with pip install.